# Spotty and Impossible Route (Closest Facility)- ArcGIS Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, network, route, closest-facility

I am trying to find the closest facility for parcels (converted my polygons to points), to existing sewer lines. In the image you can see that some sections of the green routes are just very short segments, that never reach the existing sewer lines (I converted these to points as well for use in Load Locations). How can this be a valid route when it doesn't connect the parcels to the existing sewer?

I have set up topology on the proposed sewer lines to make sure they are all connected.

I have also tried using the Advanced Options in Load Locations (Incidents which is Parcels), and setting my 'Snap to Position Along Network" with an offset of 20 meters since that is common for parcel points to be 20 meters from proposed sewer lines. This didn't change anything.

I am using Use Feature Geometry option in Location Position, and leaving default value of 5000 meters.

This is related to my previous question:
[Calculate distance from polygon to nearest existing line in geometric network, along network routes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316194/calculate-distance-from-polygon-to-nearest-existing-line-in-geometric-network-a/316267#316267)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who experience the same Closest Facility troubles as me: Some things I did to make things work better.

1. Planarize all my lines. (Advanced Editing).
2. Topology
3. Reduce my number of facilities to the lowest effective number possible ( I converted lines to points and at first was using all of them for facilities. I later took intersection of these points and proposed sewage lines, reduced my facilites from 4350 to 28).
4. Set Connectivity from End Points to Any Vertex. This is why it's very important to Planarize Lines so that every intersection has a vertex for the NetWork Dataset.
5. Reduced my Incidents by setting lower search radius to exclude data I didn't need in the network analysis.